# How to Access JSON attribute in typeScript

Tags: json, typescript, angular7

### How to access the JSON attributes in typescript ?

As I am making Angular Project.
`

```
    test:string;
    response:any;

    web_assign() {
    this.http.get(this.url1).subscribe( e => this.response = e);
    this.test = "OK";
    this.t=this.response.name2;
    return false;}
```

it is giving error on this line.
`this.t=this.response.name2;`
It says that it cannot read property of 'name2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the assignment inside  the subscribe callback:

```
this.http.get(this.url1)
    .subscribe( e => {
        this.response = e;
        this.test = "OK";
        this.t=this.response.name2;
    });
```

`http.get` is async and `this.response` will still not be defined on the next line, but it will be defined in `subscribe` callback.

Comment: based on his repoutation score, he can not accept, but here is my upvote for you XD